# Spark Scala to_timestamp() function throwing DateTimeParseException (Fail to parse) error instead of returning null

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, to-timestamp

According to the documentation to_timestamp function ideally should return null instead of throwing a Fail to parse error:

The following code throws `Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '17-08-01' could not be parsed at index 0`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, to_timestamp}
val df1 = Seq(("abc", "17-08-01")).toDF("id", "eventTime")
val df2 = df1.withColumn("eventTime1",to_timestamp(col("eventTime"),"yyyy-MM-dd"))
df2.show()
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#to_timestamp(s:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,fmt:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Based on the documentation to_timestamp function
returns -> A timestamp, or null if s was a string that could not be casted to a timestamp or fmt was an invalid format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using spark 3 ? It seems that this behaviour is no longer supported since spark 3.0 (they shoud've updated the docs) see the below error at the beginning of your stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different 
result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to parse '17-08-01' in the new parser. 
You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior 
before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.
```

If you want the pre spark 3.0 behaviour, you need to set one of these confs, the second one seems to fit more your needs:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "CORRECTED")
```

Comment: Solution tested and working on Spark 3.3

Comment: The conf `spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy` to `CORRECTED` and It's behaviour also seems to be missing in the documentation.